# PyWhatKit Python open browser but sometimes not send the message

Tags: python, whatsapp

It just opens the browser and creates the message, but after the established wait time, it closes the tab and does not send the message.

Increasing wait time value works but it fails on some occasions.

Any suggestions?

```
def whatmsg(telef, notaw):
   hoy = datetime.datetime.now()
   hora_actual = datetime.datetime(hoy.year, hoy.month, hoy.day, hoy.hour, hoy.minute)
   hora_deseada = datetime.timedelta(minutes=2)
   salida = hora_actual + hora_deseada
   print(salida)
   kit.sendwhatmsg(telef, notaw, salida.hour, salida.minute, 35, True, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
import pywhatkit as w
import pyautogui
import keyboard as k

def whatmsg(telef, notaw)
  w.sendwhatmsg_instantly(telef, notaw)
  time.sleep(2)
  pyautogui.click()
  time.sleep(1)
  k.press_and_release('enter')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).